# How do you take a R&T A-1250 toilet float valve apart?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

This is a pneumatic shutoff I believe. It has a pinhole sealed by the float arm.

Pic. of the pinhole which shuts off
[image]

Comment: Thank you Isherwood. I want to see if I can increase the flow rate. I cleaned the inlet screen but can't get the valve apart

Comment: Don't tell me down here. _Revise your question_.